# Cannot reach YUM repos on terraform EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

### background:

I used terraform to build an AWS autoscaling group with a few instances spread across availability zones and linked by a load balancer. Everything is created properly, but the load balancer has no valid targets because they're nothing listening on port 80.
Fine, I thought. I'll install NGINX and throw up a basic config.

### expected behavior

instances should be able to reach yum repos

### actual behavior

I'm unable to ping anything or run any of the package manager commands, getting the following error

```
Could not retrieve mirrorlist https://amazonlinux-2-repos-us-east-2.s3.dualstack.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2/core/latest/x86_64/mirror.list error was
12: Timeout on https://amazonlinux-2-repos-us-east-2.s3.dualstack.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2/core/latest/x86_64/mirror.list: (28, 'Failed to connect to amazonlinux-2-repos-us-east-2.s3.dualstack.us-east-2.amazonaws.com port 443 after 2700 ms: Connection timed out')


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: amzn2-core/2/x86_64
```

### troubleshooting steps taken

I'm new to Terraform, and I'm still having issues doing the automated provisioning of user_data, so I SSH'd into the instance. The instance is set up in a public subnet with an auto-provisioned public IP. Below is the code for the security groups.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "elb_webtrafic_sg" {
    name        = "elb-webtraffic-sg"
    description = "Allow inbound web trafic to load balancer"
    vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
    ingress {
        description = "HTTPS trafic from vpc"
        from_port        = 443
        to_port          = 443
        protocol         = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
    ingress {
        description = "HTTP trafic from vpc"
        from_port        = 80
        to_port          = 80
        protocol         = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
    ingress {
        description = "allow SSH"
        from_port        = 22
        to_port          = 22
        protocol         = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
    egress {
        description = "all traffic out"
        from_port        = 0
        to_port          = 0
        protocol         = "-1"
        cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
    tags        = {
        Name = "elb-webtraffic-sg"
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "instance_sg" {
    name        = "instance-sg"
    description = "Allow traffic from load balancer to instances"
    vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
    ingress {
        description = "web traffic from load balancer"
        security_groups  = [ aws_security_group.elb_webtrafic_sg.id ]
        from_port        = 80
        to_port          = 80
        protocol         = "tcp"
    }
    ingress {
        description = "web traffic from load balancer"
        security_groups  = [ aws_security_group.elb_webtrafic_sg.id ]
        from_port        = 443
        to_port          = 443
        protocol         = "tcp"
    }
    ingress {
        description = "ssh traffic from anywhere"
        from_port        = 22
        to_port          = 22
        protocol         = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
    egress {
        description = "all traffic to load balancer"
        security_groups  = [ aws_security_group.elb_webtrafic_sg.id ]
        from_port        = 0
        to_port          = 0
        protocol         = "-1"
    }
    tags        = {
        Name = "instance-sg"
    }
}

#this is a workaround for the cyclical security group id call
#I would like to figure out a way for this to destroy this first
#it currently takes longer to destroy than to set up
#terraform hangs because of the dependancy each SG has on each other, 
#but will eventually struggle down to this rule and delete it, clearing the deadlock
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "elb_egress_to_webservers" {
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.elb_webtrafic_sg.id
  type                     = "egress"
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.instance_sg.id
  from_port                = 80
  to_port                  = 80
  protocol                 = "tcp"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "elb_tls_egress_to_webservers" {
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.elb_webtrafic_sg.id
  type                     = "egress"
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.instance_sg.id
  from_port                = 443
  to_port                  = 443
  protocol                 = "tcp"
}
```

Since I was able to SSH into the machine, I tried to set up the web instance security group to allow direct connection from the internet to the instance. Same errors: cannot ping outside web addresses, same error on YUM commands.

I can ping the default gateway in each subnet. 10.0.0.1, 10.0.1.1, 10.0.2.1.

Here is the routing configuration I currently have setup.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main_vpc" {
  cidr_block    = "10.0.0.0/16"
  tags          = {
    Name = "production-vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "aws_key" {
  key_name = "Tanchwa_pc_aws"
  public_key = file(var.public_key_path)
}

#internet gateway
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name = "internet-gw"
  } 
}


resource "aws_route_table" "route_table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "production-route-table"
  }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "public_us_east_2a" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-2a"

  tags = {
    Name = "Public-Subnet us-east-2a"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_us_east_2b" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-2b"

  tags = {
    Name = "Public-Subnet us-east-2b"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_us_east_2c" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-2c"

  tags = {
    Name = "Public-Subnet us-east-2c"
  }
}


resource "aws_route_table_association" "a" {
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_us_east_2a.id
    route_table_id = aws_route_table.route_table.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "b" {
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_us_east_2b.id
    route_table_id = aws_route_table.route_table.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "c" {
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_us_east_2c.id
    route_table_id = aws_route_table.route_table.id
}
```

Comment: On your egress rule, remove `security_groups  = [ aws_security_group.elb_webtrafic_sg.id ]`.

Comment: and replace it with the 0.0.0.0/0 CIDR?

Comment: Yes, have it match what you have for the load balancer security group.

Comment: I could have sworn that was one of the first things I tried... Thanks

Comment: Your egress is only allowing traffic outbound to the loadbalancer, which is pointless because stateful security groups already allow egress to the load balancer as long as the inbound traffic is allowed. However the load balancer is not involved in traffic initiated by the EC2 instance, so your outbound traffic to the `yum` repository is not allowed.

Comment: Also mixing `aws_security_group_rule` resources with inline security group rules is not valid Terraform code. You're going to run into conflicts. Please read the big warning at the top of the `aws_security_group_rule` documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws%20%20/3.64.2/docs/resources/security_group_rule

Comment: I only did this as a workaround for when I reference one security group as the destination for the other. It won't create otherwise since it's stuck in a deadlock, each waiting for the other to create so they can get their respective IDs. 

Do you have a different solution than this that does not involve not using the security group as the path?

Comment: I ended up just creating the security group and then defining all the rules outside of it. Seems to have worked just fine.

Thanks for the guidance! Sometimes a get a little too excited and just jump into the hands on stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/terraform-ec2-userdata-yum-error/) (in Japanese) says adding dependency from aws_instance to aws_nat_gateway was required.

In the same way, adding dependency to aws_internet_gateway worked fine for my case.

ec2.tf:

```
resource "aws_instance" "your_ec2" {
    :
  depends_on = [
    aws_internet_gateway.gw
  ]

  user_data = <<EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    yum update -y
    yum install -y jq
    EOF
    :
}
```